I2 (I-squared) estimates for heterogeneity of independent meta-analysis versus a single meta-regression
I am wondering how the I2 estimates of independent meta-analyses per level of a categorical moderator compare to those of a single meta-regression. The question is similar to the one about how the estimates themselves differ and how to get both methods producing the same result, discussed, explained and implemented in the metafor R package by Wolfgang here (https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates). Using this same dataset/adapted code, here is a reproducible example demonstrating the question.
First we load metafor and the dataset:
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
dat$alloc <- ifelse(dat$alloc == "random", "random", "other")
dat

Then we do independent meta-analyses. We use the Jackson et al. (2012) approach to calculate I2s in a way that works for multilevel models since we will do a meta-regression later (https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:i2_multilevel_multivariate?s[]=jackson). This is also the reason we use rma.mv instead of rma to produce all the models.
# INDEP -------------------------------------------------------------------

res1 <- rma.mv(yi, vi,  random = ~ alloc | trial, data=dat, subset=alloc=="random")
res1_noranf <- rma.mv(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="random")
res1_I2<-c(100 * (vcov(res1)[1,1] - vcov(res1_noranf)[1,1]) / vcov(res1)[1,1])

res2 <- rma.mv(yi, vi,  random = ~ alloc | trial, data=dat, subset=alloc=="other")
res2_noranf <- rma.mv(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="other")
res2_I2<-c(100 * (vcov(res2)[1,1] - vcov(res2_noranf)[1,1]) / vcov(res2)[1,1])

dat.comp <- data.frame(alloc    = c("random", "other"), 
                       estimate = c(coef(res1), coef(res2)), 
                       stderror = c(se(res1), se(res2)),
                       tau2     = c(res1$tau2, res2$tau2))
dfround(dat.comp, 3)

rma(estimate, sei=stderror, mods = ~ alloc, method="FE", data=dat.comp, digits=3)

Then we do the same but as a meta-regression with differing amounts of residual heterogeneity to reproduce the estimates (the approach implemented by Wolfgang):
# SINGLE META-REGRESSION WITH DIFF AMOUNTS OF RESIDUAL HET --------------------------------------------------

res3<-rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc, random = ~ alloc | trial, 
       struct="DIAG", data=dat, digits=3)
res3_noranf<-rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc, 
       data=dat, digits=3)
res3_I2<-c(100 * (vcov(res3)[1,1] - vcov(res3_noranf)[1,1]) / vcov(res3)[1,1])

What I am wondering is how the I2 estimates of the independent models relate to those of the meta-regression:
#compare estimates
cbind(res1_I2,res2_I2,res3_I2)

Here they are quite similar, but it is not simply that the average I2 of res1 and res2 is the I2 of res3 for example. Furthermore, in another meta-analysis I'm doing with many more levels of the moderator (10), the I2 estimates of the independent models vary wildly from ~20% to >90% but the I2 of the meta-regression is ~96%. If someone could explain the statistics behind this a little more that would be great, please! I am assuming it is just because the I2 is quite sensitive when there are few studies, so it is more indicative of the I2s of the independent analyses being unreliable, rather than independent meta-analyses being a better approach?
Thanks
Matt

I think you might be mixing things up here. The models res1 and res2 that you have specified are the same as standard random-effects models for subsets "random" and "other", respectively. res3 is a multivariate parameterization to let residual heterogeneity differ across subgroups and get the same results with ram.mv() that would be obtained if you fitted a separate random effects model for each subgroup. See here.
The Jackson approach is a method to compute $ I^2 $ for multivariate models. But the models specified are not multivariate as we don't have specified a variance-covariance matrix of the sampling errors via argument V. See vignette provided by Viechtbauer. I think that is a key point here.
Output res1:
               estim   sqrt.
    tau^2      0.3925  0.6265      
    
    estimate  se      zval     pval     ci.lb    ci.ub      
    -0.9710   0.2760  -3.5185  0.0004   -1.5118  -0.4301  *** 

The $ I^2 $ statistics as calculated with the code provided in the question -res1_I2- yield 96.08%.
Standard random effects model with rma:
    RE.r=rma(yi,vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="random")

Output random effects model:
    tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.3925 (SE = 0.3029)
    tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.6265
    I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   89.93%
    
    estimate     se      zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub      
    -0.9710      0.2760  -3.5186  0.0004  -1.5118  -0.4301  *** 

Viechtbauer also provides background and code to calculate the $ I^2 $ statistics step by step for standard random effects models in his vignette.
    ##### I2 step by step
    W <- diag(1/res1$vi)
    X <- model.matrix(res1)
    P <- W - W %*% X %*% solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% W
    100 * sum(res1$tau2) / (sum(res1$tau2) + (res1$k-res1$p)/sum(diag(P)))

If you apply that on res1 you will get the same result as the rma() function calculates:
     [1] 89.93432

You can do the same thing for res2.
For res3 under the assumption that the meta-analyses are indepent you could compute $ I^2 $ for alloc "random" with:
    W3=1/diag(res3$vi)
    W3[!is.finite(W3)]=0
    X3=model.matrix(res3)
    P3 <- W3 - W3 %*% X3 %*% solve(t(X3) %*% W3 %*% X3) %*% t(X3) %*% W3
    100 * res3$tau2[2] / (res3$tau2[2] + (sum(dat$alloc == "random")-1)/sum(diag(P3)[dat$alloc == "random"]))

Output then:
    [1] 89.93432


Ahhh this is so helpful thank you. The terminology in meta-anlaysis is a minefield sometimes and I must admit I hadn't fully appreciated that that was the distinction between multilevel and multivariate. Thank you, this has saved me from incorrectly using the Jackson approach!
